# how do I permananently cascade permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, debian

I currently use the command `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/` to grant permissions on a folder. However if I then add a new folder under this path I need to re-issue the command in order for the new folder the be granted permissions. Is there a way to set the permissions so that any folder I create under the path automatically picks up the parents permissions?

Comment: Are you really sure that you want this? Please read the answer on http://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777 as well as http://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var

Comment: Yes I am sure I want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please never do this, it's an easy way for hackers. If you want to install a CMS or something like that just 777 or 644 the files recommended in the documentation.

Comment: I understand that, but I am fed up of having to re-issue commands every time I add a mercurial repository..... I am not sure many hackers are going to be interested in hacking into my home network and then hacking my raspberry pi.... I am not too worried about the security issue as it is already protected by a hardware firewall.